# Swing BorderLayout: Make no space between buttons, no center gap

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, border-layout

I have this code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Test extends JFrame {
    public Test()  {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();

        JButton leftButton = new JButton("Left");
        JButton rightButton = new JButton("Right");
        JButton bottomButton  = new JButton("Bottom");

        Container container = getContentPane();
        container.add(leftButton, BorderLayout.LINE_START);
        container.add(rightButton, BorderLayout.LINE_END);
        container.add(bottomButton, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);

        pack();
        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test test = new Test();
    }
}
```

When I run it, it shows:

[image]

However when I resize this window:

[image]

How do I make it so that buttons take up 100% of the windows, like this:

[image]

I tried to do this:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Test extends JFrame {
    public Test()  {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();

        JButton leftButton = new JButton("Left");
        JButton rightButton = new JButton("Right");
        JButton bottomButton  = new JButton("Bottom");

        panel.add(leftButton);
        panel.add(rightButton);

        Container container = getContentPane();
      //  container.add(leftButton, BorderLayout.LINE_START);
        //container.add(rightButton, BorderLayout.LINE_END);
        container.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        container.add(bottomButton, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);

        pack();
        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test test = new Test();
    }
}
```

but it worked even worse:

[image]

[image]

I also tried:

```
container.add(new JLabel(""), BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

but it gave the original result.

Comment: You might try a box layout.  At least one of the examples here shows a list of buttons that fill the space fully.  Box can be cranky to deal with so you might need to experiment. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/box.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This layout can be easily achieved by using a `GridLayout` (green) for the buttons, in the `CENTER` of a `BorderLayout` (red) for the main GUI.

[image]